# using cat in a bash script is very slow

Tags: bash, grep, cat, io-redirection

I have very big text files(~50,000) over which i have to do some text processing. Basically run multiple grep commands.
When i run it manually it returns in an instant , but when i do the same in a bash script - it takes a lot of time. What am i doing wrong in below bash script. I pass the names of files as command line arguments to script

Example Input data :

```
BUSINESS^GFR^GNevil
PERSONAL^GUK^GSheila
```

Output that should come in a file - BUSINESS^GFR^GNevil

It starts printing out the whole file on the terminal after quite some while. How do i suppress the same?

```
#!/bin/bash
cat $2 | grep BUSINESS
```

Comment: Why do you need to `cat` at all? Why not just `grep` directly?

Comment: What is `$($(cat $2) ` also, to grep a file don't use `cat f | grep 'something'` but `grep 'something' f`

Comment: I don't think you need `cat` here - just specify the file in the call to grep.

Comment: Okay. but when I can use the same at command line why not in a script - cat test | grep BUSINESS | grep '^GFR|^GDE'

Comment: Apart from [`UUOC`](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html#cat), this is wrong too. `cat $2 | grep ... ` might have at least given you correct results. `$(cat $2) | grep BUSINESS` is plain wrong. Essentially, the contents of `$2` would be run as command...

Comment: i pass the filenames as cmd line argument number 2, so thats what i wanted

Comment: ^^ No, `cat file | command` is different from `$(cat file) | command`. e.g. Create a file containing just a single line : `ls` & check output of `cat file | grep .` vs `$(cat file) | grep .`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do NOT use `cat` with program that can read file itself.
It slows thing down and you lose functionality:

```
grep BUSINESS test | grep '^GFR|^GDE'
```

Or you can do like this with `awk`

```
awk '/BUSINESS/ && /^GFR|^GDE/' test
```

Comment: also, how do i suppress the grep output, I changed it as below :
$(grep BUSINESS $2| grep -E "$countries")>>"$Output_File"

Comment: Do you like the output to a file?  Give example data in your original post and how you like the output to be.